# What are the best practices on editing CMake files? Portability issue

Tags: linux, cmake, libraries

As an example, I have a package that uses common libraries like boost and opencv. I have installed these packages in special locations like `~/libs/boost/build`, in contrast to `/usr/local` default locations.

In my package CMake I call boost and open cv with `` SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "~/libs/boost/.../build/include")'

The issue is as such my package is not portable in the sense the user who would try to use it would have to modify it, i.e. to modify `~/libs/boost/.../build/include`

Thus, my question is how to edit CMake or .bashrc such that my package would be portable?

Comment: I mean "portability". Am in a position where I have to share my packages, but the locations of my libraries are different from the others (who simply put all their packages in /usr/.. )...

Comment: @Florian I gave the examples of Boost and OpenCV for illustration purpose only. My question applies to any installed library to be use by my package...

Comment: Ok, but the procedure is more or less the same for all packages (the linked question does cover those aspects). You just use `find_package()` in your `CMakeLists.txt` and if the user wants to take a specific version/installation path of the package in question you give the root path on the command line with `cmake -D ...` or - if supported - an environment variable.